# How do you switch to fullscreen mode in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

Typically Runescape shows with inventory and everything open. This keeps the main game window really small.

How do you switch to a fullscreen mode like the picture below?

[image: Runescape screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is controlled by the *Display Options*. Here is RuneScape's official guide for [**Display Options**](http://www.runescape.com/kbase/guid/controls_display_options).

> To access your display settings, go to the 'Game Options' tab and select 'Graphics Options'. This will enable you to adjust the settings you have access to in your detail settings.

Comment: Its only available for members? the game says "Fullscreen mode is only for members."

Comment: Yes, correct. It is only for members. I should have added that. I have been member since the first day Andrew and his crew offered it. Which is why I thought nothing of it.

Comment: I also thought of becoming a paid member, but isn't it a monthly fee? don't you find it expensive? I'm a level 40 free player, and I've got 100Kgp and full rune/mith armor, can't really remember. What are really the advantages of becoming a member? do you find it more fun in any way?

Comment: Why don't you answer me in my separate question here .. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13245/whats-cool-about-becoming-a-member-in-runescape